# Using a regex to extract everything in a string except for an exact keyword

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have tried numerous regexs in an attempt to solve this issue but I cannot solve it. As the title suggests I am tempting to extract everything in a string except for a keyword that I know will/could be located in the string. I am using https://regex101.com/ to test my regex's. The sample strings are below.

"Job Care Worker"
"+jobs +Nurse"
"construction worker"

I've tried using a negative lookahead such as `^((?![jJ]ob).)*$` but if I plug this into https://regex101.com/, with my test strings, I am unable to remove the word Job. That is essentially my end goal here, remove the word jobs from the string.

Comment: To remove `Job`, just remove it with string functions, why match with regex?

Answer (score 2):

Simply take everythign except "job".

Select `(.*)job(.*)` and replace it with group 1 and 2 (`$1$2`)

you need the case-insensitive-flag here (`/i`)

See https://regex101.com/r/hRFNUe/1

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chriz, This works on the website which is awesome, but I actually need to embed this regex into a javascript for a UDF in BigQuery. Can JS do substitutions?

Comment: @JaredRieger for information on how to execute the regex in JS and how to acces groups, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression) . You'd need match 1 and 2 here, match 0 is the whole matched regex